# Use of logical operators in Leap year problem

Tags: c, if-statement, leap-year, logical-or, logical-and

I am quite new in this programming world and my question may sound silly but can anyone explain difference between following 2 codes.

**Code 1**

```
    int yr;
    printf("enter the respective year=\n");
    scanf("%d", &yr);
    if(yr%400==0 || yr%100!=0 && yr%4==0)
        printf("It is a leap year\n");
    else
        printf("It is not a leap year\n");

    return 0;
```

**Code 2**

```
    int yr;
    printf("enter the respective year=\n");
    scanf("%d", &yr);
    if((yr%100==0 && yr%400==0) || yr%4==0)
        printf("It is a leap year\n");
    else
        printf("It is not a leap year\n");

    return 0;
```

I think both should work well but when I executed them then only Code 1 is giving right answers.

Comment: `yr%400=0` will result in compilation error.

Comment: `yr%100==0 && yr%400==0` is equivalent to `yr%400==0` because 400 is multiple of 100.

Comment: @MikeCAT Hmm I realized it now ,thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition in the if statement

```
if(yr%400==0 || yr%100!=0 && yr%4==0)
```

that can be equivalently rewritten using parentheses like

```
if ( ( yr%400==0 ) || ( yr%100!=0 && yr%4==0 ) )
```

means that a leap year is the year that either divisible by `400` or divisible by `4` and at the same time is not divisible by `100`.

For example the year `1900` is not a leap year because it is not divisible by `400` and on the other hand is divisible by `100`.

The condition in this if statement

```
if((yr%100==0 && yr%400==0) || yr%4==0)
```

means that any year divisible by 4 is a leap year due to the second sub-expression `yr%4==0` that always yields logical true for any year divisible by 4. So it is even unimportant what will be the logical result of the first sub-expression `(yr%100==0 && yr%400==0)` because any number divisible by 100 and 400 is divisible at the same time by 4.

So the second if statement is logically wrong. It accepts the `year` 1900 as a leap year.

Comment: Second if statement: I don't think it matters whether the logical result of the first subexpression is true or false, i.e. who cares that "any number divisible by 100 and 400 is divisible at the same time by 4" is true or not? When there is || and one of the expressions is true, then the test result is true

Answer (score 0):

expressions

```
(yr%400==0 || yr%100!=0 && yr%4==0)   /* (yr%400==0 || (  yr%100!=0 && yr%4==0))*/
```

and

```
( yr%100!=0 && yr%4==0 || yr%400==0 )   /* ( (yr%100!=0 && yr%4==0) || yr%400==0 )*/
```

are correct, but to to avoid confusion better to use parentheis. Both are evaluated(grouped for calculation) differently as shown in the comment. Evaluation order is based on operator precedence rules(&&  has precedence over ||).

Answer (score 0):

There is a collision of two complications: the leap year rule itself and the logical operators. The `&&` binds tighter than `||` but that is not even the deeper problem.

A (nested) `if...else` might be overkill.

The conditional `?:` seems perfect. I can leave out the `==0` plus the NOT `!=`. Just place the 0/1 at the right spot. This gives a regular pattern:

```
int isleap(int y) {

    return
    y%4 ?            // normal year?
      0              // done
      : y%100 ?      // Candidate. Not a century?
         1           // normal leap
         : y%400 ?   // Century. normal one?
            0        // 100 normal century   
            : 1      // 400 special century
    ;                     // return's semicolon
}
```

The ternary conditional expression is *between* the logical expressions and the if-statement. With logical expressions it is a bit hard to safely gather both "1" cases together.

"Oh but this takes more lines."

Yes. Or do you want to copy paste that one-line logical expression regularly? And it can be put on a line, looks only 20% worse than &&||-versions.

(nobody really asked, talking with myself)

"Oh it is a whole function"

`inline` is an official function-specifier, if speed matters.

---

Why I am saying is log. expr. are tricky in this case. The "standard" 4-100-400-no-parens-middle-not formula:

```
 return y%4 == 0 && y%100 != 0 || y%400 == 0;
```

makes the compiler suggest parens around the `&&` part. But even with wrong parens you get the right result. Set theory? Inverted double exception?